# var+= adds string instead of sum

Tags: shell, scripting

I have to make a script that makes the sum of all processes that have PIDS greater than 20. It kind of works but something is going wrong. I know it's something simple, base thing, but I can't get the logic.

For example I have 2 processes, "1504" and "1405". My result of sum is 15041405. How do I have to re-write sum+=${proc[$i]} to make an actual sum, not string attach?

```
proc=( $(ps | cut -d ' ' -f1) )

nr=$(ps | cut -d ' ' -f1 | wc -l)

sum=0

for (( i=0 ; i<=nr ; i++)); do

[[ ${proc[$i]} -gt 20 ]] && sum+=${proc[$i]}


done


echo $sum
```

Comment: Everything is treated in as a string in shell unless you've gone out of your way to make it otherwise (by being in a math context, or leveraging the almost-never-used support in bash for declared integer varuables) -- so it should be no surprise for `foo+=bar` to be string concatenation unless you go out of your way to make it otherwise.

Comment: By the way -- why in the world are you doing `ps | cut | wc -l`? The content of the lines is thrown away, so what value does the `cut` add? Personally, I wouldn't use ps at all, and would directly inspect `/proc/[0-9]*`.

Comment: ...I'm also not sure what value you get from summing the PIDs, rather than counting them, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a math context. In POSIX sh:

```
sum=$(( sum + val ))
```

...or, also valid POSIX:

```
: "$(( sum += val ))"
```

...or, in bash:

```
(( sum += val ))
```

You can also use much easier-to-read comparison operations in a math context, rather than using -gt inside of a non-math test context. In bash:

```
(( ${proc[$i]} >= 20 )) && (( sum += ${proc[$i]} ))
```

...or in POSIX shell (which doesn't support arrays, and so cannot exactly reproduce your sample code):

```
: "$(( sum += ( val < 20 ) ? 0 : val ))"
```

---

If you were trying to do the (more sensible) operation of **counting** PIDs, I'd consider an implementation more like the following (bash-only and Linux-only, but considerably more efficient):

```
count=0
for pid_file in /proc/[0-9]*; do
  pid=${pid_file##*/}
  (( pid > 20 )) && (( count++ ))
done
printf '%s\n' "$count"
```

...or, to put more of the effort on the glob engine:

```
# avoid inflating the result with non-matching globs
shopt -s nullglob

# define a function to avoid overwriting the global "$@" array
count_procs() {
  set -- /proc/[3-9][0-9] /proc/[0-9][0-9][0-9]*
  echo "$#"
}

# ...used as follows:
count_procs
```